# What instead of createTextNode to not avoid XML paragraphs

Tags: php, xml

I've got a php code which gets external xml file, adds something before last paragraph and saves it as new file.

```
<?php
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('xml.xml');


    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;

    $newElement = $xmldoc->createTextNode('<o id="1" url="link.html" price="899.00" avail="1" weight="0" stock="0" set="0" basket="0"></o>');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);

    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');
?>
```

However, I don't want to lose XML signs like " <> ". What should I use instead of createTextNode? Because by now I've got a code like this:

```
&lt;o id="1" url="link.html" price="899.00" avail="1" weight="0" stock="0" set="0" basket="0"&gt;&#13;
```

Answer (score 1):

DOMDocument::createTextNode() does exactly that it creates a node containing text. It does not loose the special characters - they will be encoded as entities for the serialization.

Here are other methods like DOMDocument::createElement() to create an element node and DOMElement::setAttribute() to set attributes on an element node.

If you have an XML fragment as a string literal, here is a node type that can consume it. The DOMDocumentFragment.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$root = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('foo'));
$fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml('<p>some text</p>');
$root->appendChild($fragment);
echo $document->saveXml();
```

Document fragments are kind of virtual nodes, the are a list of nodes with a single node as a container so that they can be passed to the DOM methods. Be careful using DOMDocumentFragment:appendXml() or you might open yourself to HTML/XML injections.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching [createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php).

```
<?php
$newElement = $xmldoc->createTextNode('o');
$newElement->setAttribute("url", "link.html");
```

You can then add attributes to match with your example.

See [setAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php). createTextNode creates only a text node, no XML. createElement, creates an XML element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it really necessary to make all my attributes like this? My code is quite longer than shown.

Comment: It seems necessary. createElement does not allow to set attributes.